# Set class instance to be an object (google map)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, class, object

I am trying to use Google map on my website. I decided to create class "map", so I can use class methods and objects.

The problem is: I would like the class constructor to know that each instance of this class is automatically a Google map. 
So when I call:

```
map = new map(location);
```

I will get a Google map and "this" will refer to that map. This is my constructor:

```
map.prototype = new Element();
map.prototype.constructor = map;

function map (place) {
    this.dom = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(this.dom);

    // here I am trying to set "this" to the google map
    // option 1: obviously wrong
    // this = new google.maps.Map(this.dom, {zoom: 9, center: place.location});

    // option 2: overwrites dom, but I want dom to be the div
    // this.dom = new google.maps.Map(this.dom, {zoom: 9, center: place.location});

    //option 3: this works, I don't want to have this extra sub-step using this."map".something...
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.dom, {zoom: 9, center: place.location});         


    // call other functions, etc...
};
```

Is there any way to do it better? Without having to create another object property and put the map in it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the new Class syntax to make it more readable:

```
class Map extends google.maps.Map {
  constructor(){
     super(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')), {zoom: 9, center: place.location});

  }

  customMethod(){
     this.whatever();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your approach correctly, it makes my map class inherit everything from the google.maps.Map class. But, it is not a Google map itself. Is that correct? Are there any differences between this approach and my approach (Option 3)?

Comment: Also, I get an error:

    Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: @jan yes and as it *inherits* everything, its a google map itself